# Scale on content editable div in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-transforms

In Firefox using scale transform causes the cursor to stop blinking, or hides it or makes it point to the wrong character.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7bNU4/4/

```
<div tabindex="1" class="trans">    
<div contenteditable="true">
   <span style="font-size: 73px; font-family: Calibri (Headings);
    text-align: center; color: Black;" class="TxtPhLineTxt">S</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.trans { 
    height: 2.1in; width: 11.5in; 
    cursor: text; 
    transform: scale(0.461111);
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

So, is there any solution to above problem?

Comment: It actually doesn't hide, if you zoom, you will see the cursor blinking, its just the zoom in issue'

Comment: As @Mr.Alien notes its just a zoom artefact. Changing the level to .45 or .47 resolves it

Comment: @SW4 what is the point of using scale if you hardcode the value, atleast in my case, I am resizing so scale value changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in firefox, which has not been resolved yet :

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865930

Comment: I won't call it as a bug though